# Personal Hotspot for iPad 2 3G

Tags: ipad, wifi, cellular-data, tethering

I'm thinking about getting an iPad 2 3g & I was wondering if one can set up a personal hotspot from the iPad to share the 3G internet with wifi enabled devices (i.e laptop etc.)

Is it possible in any way to tether an iPhone or other devices to the iPad, rather than using an iPhone to tether against which is the normal method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No unfortunately, with the current 4.3 version of iOS on the iPad, there is not Personal Hotspot feature on the ipad.   This may be different on the upcoming iOS 5.

Comment: Is it? (9 more to go…)